# YouTube Application Crashed

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I integrated YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi in my project.  While loading the video, press the device back button.
Observation: Youtube player has stopped with an alert and YouTube App Crashed. So how can I prevent crashing the YouTube Application.

I am using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.1. Downloaded from developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads –

Comment: Post the relevant logcat along with source code that you have tried.

Comment: please post some code and error you are getting.

Comment: If you don't provide any code to reproduce the problem, or even a backtrace, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed on their latest play service.